# Working of Process Memory/Garbage Collector

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, visual-studio-2015

I have been trying to understand working of Process Memory. So I tried following piece of code

```
    public void OpenFormWithoutList()
    {
        Form2 form = null;
        int index = 0;
        while (index < 5000)
        {
            form = new Form2();
            form.ShowDialog();
            index++;
        }
    }
    public void OpenFormWithList()
    {
        Form2 form = null;
        List<Form> list = new List<Form>();
        int index = 0;
        while (index < 5000)
        {
            form = new Form2();
            list.Add(form);
            form.ShowDialog();
            index++;
        }
        list = null;
    }
```

And in Form2.cs I am closing the form in OnLoad event, so that control should come back to Parent Form (Form1) again.

When I run both the methods seprately from start, following is the observation after the method executes:

Start: 20 MB 
OpenFormWithList(): 29MB

Start: 20MB
OpenFormWithoutList(): 25MB

When OpenFormWithoutList() is called, GC is collecting the forms, so memory usage is not going up to 29MB. But once these method gets over then too memory usage doesn't comes back to starting phase, i.e. 20MB.

So why isn't memory getting cleared and what exactly is consuming the memory?

Comment: Side note: `list = null;` is, at best, redundant. The GC and JIT collaborate to understand the lifetime of variables. They already know, at the end of the method, that the `list` variable is no longer a "live" reference, and that variable can not be used to keep the referenced object alive.

Comment: Do keep in mind that there are limited numbers of resource handles that each form needs. It could complicate your tests. It's probably better to avoid using any form of UI for memory tests.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Garbage Collection doesn't release memory immediately after any instance dispose. It has been optimized to trigger and release memory only when there is a memory stress. So, if you want to test for memory leaks you should execute Garbage Collection manually before you take counter readings.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: You want another `GC.Collect` after the `WaitForPendingFinalizers` call - otherwise the memory used by the instances that were being finalized will not be reclaimed.

Comment: @Luaan: If there are any Disposable objects with Finalization and haven't been disposed, you need to call GC.Collect() once more.

Answer (score 2):

.NET uses a generational garbage collector, and doesn't have anything like deterministic memory allocation (unless you resort to unsafe code and structures everywhere, of course).

The most relevant part here is that on every allocation, the runtime checks how much memory has been allocated since the last attempt at garbage collection - and if this passes a certain threshold, the collection begins. So it will go through the whole of memory (for a generation 2 collection - the lower generation collects only go through lower generation heaps), note all the objects that have no references to them, and clears them out. Finally, it will *compact* the heap - move all the objects around to make a contiguous space in the heap. This is very important, since .NET doesn't allocate in the middle of the heap[1] - it's something like a souped-up stack that allows "popping" from the middle.

When this is done, all the surviving objects are promoted to the next generation heap (unless they are already at the maximum generation, two at the time of this writing).

This is the difference between the variant with the list, and the variant without. With more allocations, the old form instances were reclaimed as you'd expect - but only when there's enough allocations in the first place. There's other hidden costs as well - quite possibly, the first initialization required the loading of some library or some initialization that's shared. That's why you always want to use some form of warm-up before doing any tests. Also, process memory isn't really all that important anyway - if you want to troubleshoot memory issues, CLR Profiler or something similar are much more useful.

You can force the garbage collector to do its work by calling `GC.Collect`, though this is ill advised. You shouldn't really need it, pretty much ever. Just get used to not having perfect control over memory allocation and deallocation - you're on a multi-threaded, pre-emptively multitasked, memory-virtualized system, quite possibly distributed nowadays. Precise control over memory is an illusion anyway :D

Another important point is misunderstanding of yet another thing about the compiler and runtime. Assigning `null` to a local doesn't really do anything - if you're running outside of a debugger, the local will be eligible for collection as soon as it's no longer going to be used. If you're running inside of a debugger, all locals are preserved for the whole scope (to aid in debugging, of course). Also, avoid initializing locals when you don't have a reasonable value to initialize them with - you're robbing yourself of the compiler's help in showing unexpected codepaths.

[1] Note that this only applies to the main heaps. The large object heap does indeed allow allocating in the middle, and it doesn't compact. Since .NET 4.5, there's an option to manually force a heap collection on the LOH.